# Wordpress plugins it asks for FTP Details

Tags: wordpress, plugins

While I am trying to upgrade the wordpress plugins it Asks for FTP Details.

I have added the following to wp-config.php

```
 define('FTP_USER', 'username');

 define('FTP_PASS', 'password');

 define('FTP_HOST', 'host address');
```

It has worked fine. 
But I have multiple websites working on my virtualmin server. All the wordpress site is having the same wordpress plugin issue. So is there any other fix that could resolve the Issue?

Comment: I just did a double take because I've never heard of this. What plugin exactly is asking for this information in order to upgrade?

Comment: All the plugins are asking for the ftp details. No plugins in specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found these: [link 1](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-install-asks-for-ftp-details) and [link 2](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-install-asks-for-ftp-details), where I dug out this:

> WordPress asks for your FTP credentials when it can't access the files directly. This is usually caused by PHP running as the apache user (mod_php or CGI) rather than the user that owns your WordPress files (suPHP or FastCGI). Switching over to using suPHP or FastCGI would probably fix it. Of course, if you don't want to mess with that, you can always just put your FTP credentials directly in wp-config.php or use this in the shell:

```
 pae$ cd /var/ww
 pae$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
```

Comment: I also found this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20140926070648/http://bornvirtual.com/wordpress/stop-wordpress-asking-ftp-details/713/ which may also be useful.

Comment: I have changed the permission of wp-content apache:apache, Now the Issue has been resolved.
So how could I change the apache:apache to the username:username for there corresponding sites

Comment: as a note for me and others, `$ sudo chown -R www:www [wp-folder]` worked for me on Mac OSX. The above solution didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with wordpress installation on apache is to use the secondary user and group to apache which would not cause these issue while updating or installing plugins and using other wordpress functions.
just change your apache config file User and Group to your username and group name
User [yourusername]
Group [yourgroupname]

Answer (score 0):

In wp-config just write

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Are you hosting your WordPress sites on one of those hosts where WordPress asks you to provide FTP details before upgrading itself or upgrading plugins?
So Now WordPress will stop asking you for FTP details Here’s how you can do it
Open your wp-config.php file locate in your wordpress root directory
And copy and past below detail after your database detail block in wp-config.php file

```
define(“FTP_HOST”, “ftp.yourhost.com”);
define(“FTP_USER”, “ftpusername”);                                           
define(“FTP_PASS”, “ftppassword”);
```